# How to set active menu in prime ng panel menu?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

This is the dashboard screen after login. The active menu is `/dashboard` but it is not highlighted in the panel menu.

[image]

After clicking on any of the menu, then only panel menu is highlighted. How to highlight the defalut active menu in panel menu. I am using prime ng 9 version.

[image]

side-bar-component.html

```
<ng-container>
  <p-sidebar   
    [showCloseIcon]="false"  
   >
    <div class="img">
      <h4>Logo</h4>
    </div>

    <p-panelMenu [model]="items" [style]="{ width: '100%' }" [multiple]="false"></p-panelMenu>
  </p-sidebar>
</ng-container>
```

side-bar-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { MenuItem } from 'primeng/api'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-bar',
  templateUrl: './side-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-bar.component.scss']
})
export class SideBarComponent implements OnInit {

  items: MenuItem[]
 
  ngOnInit() {  

    this.items = [
      {
        label: 'Dashboard',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-chart-bar',
        routerLink: ['/dashboard'],
        routerLinkActiveOptions: { exact: true },
      },
      {
        label: 'Magazines & Books',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-bookmark',
        routerLink: ['/e-books'],
        routerLinkActiveOptions: { exact: true },
      },
      {
        label: 'Orders',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-shopping-cart',
        routerLink: ['/orders'],
        routerLinkActiveOptions: { exact: true },
      },
      {
        label: 'Subscriptions',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-money-bill',
        routerLink: ['/subscriptions'],
        routerLinkActiveOptions: { exact: true },
      },
      {
        label: 'Users',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user',       
        items: [
          {
            label: 'Admins',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user-plus',           
            routerLink: ['/admins'],
            routerLinkActiveOptions: { exact: true },
          },
          {
            label: 'Editors',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user-edit',          
            routerLink: ['/editors'],
            routerLinkActiveOptions: { exact: true },
          },
          {
            label: 'Customers',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-users',
            routerLink: ['/customers'],
            routerLinkActiveOptions: { exact: true },
          }
        ]
      }
    ]    
  }
}
```

```
.ui-panelmenu .ui-panelmenu-content {
  border: 1px solid #f8f9fa !important;
}

.ui-panelmenu .ui-panelmenu-header > a {
  border: 1px solid #f8f9fa !important;
  background-color: #f8f9fa !important;
  padding: 1.5em 1.8em !important;
  color: #797777 !important;
}

.ui-panelmenu .ui-panelmenu-header > a:focus {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.ui-panelmenu-header.ui-state-active > a {
  // background-color: #e10101 !important;
  color: black !important;
  border-right: 5px solid red !important;
}

.ui-panelmenu .ui-panelmenu-icon {
  float: right !important;
}

.ui-panelmenu .ui-submenu-list {
  margin: 1.5em !important;
}

.ui-panelmenu .ui-panelmenu-content .ui-menuitem .ui-menuitem-link {
  padding: 1em 0.8em !important;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55217729/primeng-panelmenu-active-state-for-menu-items-and-submenu-items